# How can we get Nth highest salareid record from emp table in hibernate without using native query?

Tags: hibernate

I need nth highest salaried record from emp table in hibernate but without using native query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use paging:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("... ORDER BY salary DESC");
q.setFirstResult(Nth);
q.setMaxResults(1);
```

Works with `Criteria`s as well.